# How to unzip unzip multipar/form-data in Erlang?

Tags: http, erlang, unzip

I have a Erlang application and I need to read a zip file pass in a POST request. At the moment I'm use this solution but return an error.

```
FileUnziped = zip:unzip(Payload),
```

I pass in a body of a post request like this image

[image: postman request]

And the error is:

```
{error,bad_eocd}
```

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Can you unzip Payload with one of your unzip command line tools to check if the file is corrupted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the `Payload`/`*.zip` data/file what you try `unzip` is damaged or improperly packed, see logic in [zip.erl](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/zip.erl).
Here is example:

```erlang
1> {ok, Data} = file:read_file("tester.txt.zip").
{ok,<<80,75,3,4,10,0,0,0,0,0,133,165,69,81,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,...>>}
2> zip:unzip(Data).                                   
{ok,["tester.txt"]}
3> zip:unzip(<<Data/binary, "break archive">>).    
{error,bad_eocd}
```

Make sure that in `Payload` provided correct data.